# It is illegal to buy drugs in the countries, though there are exceptions. (meaning of "there are exceptions")

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **It is illegal to buy drugs in the countries, though there are exceptions.**

Does that sentence has the only one meaning? Does "exceptions" mean "it is legal action in other (non-mentioned) countries? Or does "exceptions" mean "it can be legal action in some areas in the (mentioned) countries? So, are "exceptions" connected with "It is illegal" or with "the countries"?

Comment: "though there are exceptions" is redundant, it's already implied by "most"...

Comment: The whole sentence is unclear because it *isn't* illegal to buy drugs in any country that I know of. There are, however, many drugs which can only be obtained on the prescription of a medical practitioner, and it is illegal in most countries to buy such drugs without a prescription. And there are some drugs which can't even be prescribed. Perhaps the question would be clearer if it referred to a *specific* drug.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko, You are right. I have done correction.

Comment: Are you asking for proofreading of a sentence you have written, or is a sentence you have seen somewhere? It makes even less sense since the edit. When many people talk about 'buying drugs' they usually mean 'illegal drugs' anyway.

Comment: [ I have made **the** correction; or; I corrected it.]

Comment: @Weather Vane, It is just my example. You can change "drugs" with another word, if it is better.

Comment: The sentence is unclear partly because of the strange wording of "*the* countries".  What countries?  "The" countries makes it sound like "some countries we have already discussed", but there isn't any context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: This was an answer to the original question, which said "most countries" rather than "the countries".

The natural meaning is that there are some countries where it is not illegal; but there are other possible readings. Another one is that it is legal in some circumstances.

I think if a writer used it in anything other than the first sense they could reasonably be accused of writing unclearly.

Comment: In what circumstance would you use "in the countries", and not say "in some countries"?

Comment: The OP has edited _in most countries_ to _in the countries_ since I answered. _In the countries_ unambiguously implies a specific set of countries, presumably identified previously.

Comment: That makes it worse for me. I don't see "in the countries"; in these countries, in those countries, in the countries listed below/above, but not just "in the countries".

Comment: @Lambie, I don't know why you're commenting about the OP's edit on my answer, which was addressed to the original version of the question.

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify that in your answer: in most countries, in some countries.